# Detecting network status change and starting service from broadcast receiver

Tags: android

I have written the following code for detecting the network status from within the BroadcastReceiver. I start a service when the network is available and stop the service when the network is not available.

I have the following class level variable.

```
private boolean IsNetworkAlreadyConnected = false;
```

Within onCreate method of the main class I start the service if the internet is available.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    if (InternetConnectivity.isConnected(MainActivity.this)) {
                IsNetworkAlreadyConnected = true;

                Intent timerIntent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), InActivityTimer.class);
                startService(timerIntent);
            }
}
```

and below is the code for my BroadcastReceiver in the same class,

```
public class mConnectivityCheckReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        String action = intent.getAction();

        if (action.equals("android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE")) {

            try {
                boolean networkAvailable = InternetConnectivity.isConnected(context);

                if (networkAvailable) {
                    if (!IsNetworkAlreadyConnected) {   
                        Intent timerIntent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), InActivityTimer.class);
                        startService(timerIntent);
                        IsNetworkAlreadyConnected = true;
                    } 
                    else {
                        Log.d("KC_HomeActivity", "Network was already connected. No need to start service again.");
                    }
                }
                else {

                    Log.d("KC_HomeActivity", "Network Disconnected. Service Stopped.");
                    IsNetworkAlreadyConnected = false;
                    Intent timerIntent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), InActivityTimer.class);
                    stopService(timerIntent);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
            }
        }
    }
};
```

When both Mobile data and Wifi are turned on then the service is started from onCreate method and it is not started again in the BroadcastReceiver but when I turn off the Wifi the Android changes the network mode to Mobile Data but for few seconds there is no internet connectivity and the service is stopped and then started again. I don't want to do this. If there is no connectivity only then the service should be stopped. If the network is shifting from Wifi to Mobile Data then the service should not be stopped.

Note: To check the internet connectivity I am using,

```
NetworkInfo info = InternetConnectivity.getNetworkInfo(context);
return (info != null && info.isConnectedOrConnecting());
```

Answer (score 2):

Network connections aren't that precise.  You should make it relax a bit, or you'll pull your hair out.

I would implement a smoothing function from the broadcasts.  When you get a connectivity change notification, set a timeout for like 15 seconds.  At that time, check your status and either start, stop, or do nothing.  If another broadcast comes in, clear the first and reset for another 15 seconds.  That will give the device time to reconnect.

Comment: You are right but I think that is why there are two methods for it. info.isConnected and info.isConnectedOrConnecting(). This should have cater for the problem I am having. Strange if it doesn't handle this situation.

Comment: It is what it is.  Networks just aren't that smooth.  I'm sure some devices would work the way you expect, but some won't.